# Difference between static enum and static struct

Tags: swift

Let say that enum or struct are static if they don't store any values in instances. Is there is any difference between static enum and static struct?

```
enum StaticEnum {
    static var someStaticVar = 0
    static func someStaticFunc() {}
}

struct StaticStruct {
    static var someStaticVar = 0
    static func someStaticFunc() {}
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585344/swift-constants-struct-or-enum.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The main difference is that you cannot construct an enum with no cases. Therefore if you're just looking for something to serve as a namespace for some static members, an enum is preferred as you cannot accidently create an instance.

```
let e = StaticEnum() // error: 'StaticEnum' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
let s = StaticStruct() // Useless, but legal
```

Comment: Using `enum` as a way of name spacing seems odd. I found it pretty unclear at first. But I'm not sure it's worth having a seperate `namespace` construct that acts essentially like a case-less `enum`

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I certainly agree that it feels a bit weird using a case-less enumeration as a namespace, it feels like more like a useful side-effect than an intended feature. Although given how infrequently 'just a namespace' is actually needed (I can only think of one example in the stdlib, [`MemoryLayout<T>`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/memorylayout), but even that takes advantage of a generic parameter so isn't quite 'just a namespace'), I can understand the lack of a `namespace` construct.