# Get value of enum type in swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get a default value for the enum so I can use it as a param. This code isn't working, but I'd like to get something like:

```
print("Param: \(Params.RCLoss.description)")
```

and the output should be:

```
Param: RC_LOSS_MAN
```

Here is the code:

```
enum Params {
  enum RCLoss: Int32, CustomStringConvertible {
    case disable = 0
    case enable = 1

    var description: String {
        return "RC_LOSS_MAN"
    }
  } 
}
```

I want to be able to pass this:

```
set(parameterType: Params.RCLoss.description, parameterValue: Params.RCLoss.enable)
```

which should correspond to these values being set:

```
set(parameterType: "RC_LOSS_MAN", parameterValue: 0)
```

Comment: `.rawValue` should return you the `Int32`. Swift Guide: "You access the raw value of an enumeration case with its rawValue property."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use of "static" keyword if "let" keyword used to define constants/immutables in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574876/what-is-the-use-of-static-keyword-if-let-keyword-used-to-define-constants-im)

Comment: It is Swift naming convention to name all your enumeration types starting with an uppercase letter `enum RCLoss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want just

```
enum rcLoss: Int32 {
  case disable = 0
  case enable = 1 

  static var description: String {
    return "RC_LOSS_MAN"
  }
}
```

`rcLoss` is a type, `description` has to be `static` for you to be able to call `rcLoss.description`. And that means you cannot use `CustomStringConvertible`. You would use `CustomStringConvertible` to convert *enum values* to a `String`.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

From [Swift Book - Enumerations](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html):

> You access the raw value of an enumeration case with its rawValue property.

```
set(parameterType: Params.rcLoss.description, parameterValue: Params.rcLoss.enable.rawValue)
```

If you can though I would use the enumeration as the type of the formal parameter so that someone can't pass an invalid value to that function. Also I'm assuming that there is a reason you have nested an enum inside of an otherwise empty enum...

Comment: Given the name "Params," I suspect they're using the outer enum as a [poor man's namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022242/difference-between-static-enum-and-static-struct) (and there are other properties that aren't relevant to the question).